# Custom error message in Zend Form is not showing

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks

I wrote some code for adding a custom error message to a zend framework element, the thing is the error doesn't show up. I've the following part of relevant code: (I can get in the else where to add the errormessage).

```
        if($this->_request->isPost() && $form->isValid($this->_request->getPost())){
            $afgehandeldValue = $form->getValue('afgehandeld');
            if($afgehandeldValue == 0)
            {
                $conversationValues['conversation_handled'] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                $checkFollowUp = $form->getValue('opvolging');
                if($checkFollowUp == 0)
                {
                    $conversationValues['conversation_handled'] = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    $form->getElement('opvolging')
                    ->addError('Je mag niemand opgeven voor een opvolgend gesprek als afgehandeld is aangevinkt.')
                    ->markAsError();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work (`markAsError()` is not needed as `addError()` automatically marks this element as invalid). Maybe your conditions are incorrect? Try to *echo* something just before setting error to see if this part of code is actually is run.

Comment: I echo'd something there I did get output and I got rid of markAsError but still no succes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using zf1
you can add a custom error message in your zend form itself no need to do it in controller as you are doing.

```
 $this->addElement('text', 'text', array(         
        'required'   => true,
        'validators' => array(              
            array('NotEmpty',true,'options' => array('messages' => 'please enter some text')),
        ),
        'label'      => 'Text Element:',
        'placeholder'=>"Insert Text",                                     
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Zend framework 1.X and want that specific form element to show errors you can do that in the form Element like this.

```
 $opvolging  = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('opvolging',
                            array('placeholder' => 'opvolging')
                     );               


$opvolging          ->setLabel('opvolging : ')
                  ->setRequired(true)
                     ->addFilter('StripTags')
                 ->setAttrib('accept-charset', 'utf-8')
                 ->addFilter('StringTrim')
                 ->addValidator('NotEmpty')
                     ->getValidator('NotEmpty')->setMessage('Je mag niemand opgeven voor een opvolgend gesprek als afgehandeld is aangevinkt.');
```

and in your Action controller

```
 $opvolging =   $form->getValue('opvolging');
```